# Calling classmethods through a dictionary

Tags: python, class, methods, dictionary

I'm working on a class describing an object that can be expressed in several "units", I'll say, to keep things simple.  Let's say we're talking about length.  (It's actually something more complicated.)  What I would like is for the user to be able to input 1 and "inch", for example, and automatically get member variables in feet, meters, furlongs, what have you as well.  I want the user to be able to input any of the units I am dealing in, and get member variables in all the other units.  My thought was to do something like this:

```
class length:
  @classmethod
  def inch_to_foot(cls,inch):
  # etc.
  @classmethod
  def inch_to_meter(cls,inch):
  # etc.
```

I guess you get the idea.  Then I would define a dictionary in the class:

```
  from_to={'inch':{'foot':inch_to_foot,'meter':inch_to_meter, ...},
           'furlong':{'foot':furlong_to_foot, ...},
           #etc
           }
```

So then I think I can write an __init__ method

```
   def __init__(self,num,unit):
       cls = self.__class__
       setattr(self,unit,num)
       for k in cls.from_to[unit].keys:
           setattr(self,k,cls.from_to[unit][k](num)
```

But no go.  I get the error "class method not callable".  Any ideas how I can make this work?  Any ideas for scrapping the whole thing and trying a different approach?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think you want to have square brackets around the keys in your `from_to` dict in the second code block (you should have `{'inch':{'foot':inch_to_foot,...},...}`)

Also, is there reason you want a dictionary of methods like this? The way you've written it, you will have to write a method for each combination (from, to) anyway, so I'm not sure what you gain syntactically or otherwise by being able to say `from_to['inch']['meter'](num)` vs `inch_to_meter(num)` -- or `convert(num, 'inch', 'meter')` etc.

Comment: @ Kyle Travis  Yep.  I edited the question.  This was not a problem in the original code, so it is not the root of my error.  But thanks.  What I hope to gain here is that I don't have to put in a bunch of if statements, "if inch then call this this and this", "if meter call this this and this" etc.

Comment: @bob.sacamento I've updated my answer with a possible alternative that you might like better. See what you think!

Comment: What units do you plan on actually storing the member variable's values in?

Comment: @martineau Well, it's more complicated than that.  The length thing is just an example.  The point is that my class needs to describe an object that can be expressed in a number of ways, and I want the user to be free to instantiate it in any of those ways, and automatically get all the other expressions.  Another example (still not what I am really doing) would be a 3D rotation: it can be expressed as a rotation matrix, quaternions, axis-angle, euler angles, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move the `from_to` variable into `__init__` and modify it to something like:

```
cls.from_to={'inch':{'foot':cls.inch_to_foot,'meter':cls.inch_to_meter, }}
```

then I think it works as you expect.

Unfortunately I can't answer **why** because i haven't used classmethods much myself, but I think it is something to do with bound vs unbound methods. Anyway, if you print the functions stored in `to_from` in your code vs the ones with my modification you'll see they are different (mine are bound, yours are classmethod objects)

Hope that helps somewhat!

**EDIT**: I've thought about it a bit more, I think the problem is because you are storing a reference to the functions before they have been bound to the class (not surprising that the binding happens once the rest of the class has been parsed). My advice would be to forget about storing a dictionary of function references, but to store (in some representation of your choice) strings that indicate the units you can change between. For instance you might choose a similar format, such as:

```
from_to = {'inch':['foot','meter']}
```

and then look up the functions during `__init__` using `getattr`
E.G.:

```
class length:    
    from_to = {'inch':['foot','meter']}

    def __init__(self,num,unit):
        if unit not in self.from_to:
            raise RuntimeError('unit %s not supported'%unit)

        cls = self.__class__
        setattr(self,unit,num)

        for k in cls.from_to[unit]:
            f = getattr(cls,'%s_to_%s'%(unit,k))
            setattr(self,k,f(num))            

    @classmethod
    def inch_to_foot(cls,inch):
        return inch/12.0

    @classmethod
    def inch_to_meter(cls,inch):
        return inch*2.54/100    

a = length(3,'inches')
print a.meter
print a.foot
print length.inch_to_foot(3)
```

Comment: Actually, that second method is pretty slick.  Would give you another upvote if I could.  Going to hold off on acceptance for a day or two just to see what else might come along.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think doing with an `__init__()` method would be a good idea. I once saw an interesting way to do it in the [*Overriding the __new__ method*](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#__new__) section of in the classic document titled [Unifying types and classes in Python 2.2](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/) by Guido van Rossum.

Here's some examples:

```
class inch_to_foot(float):
    "Convert from inch to feet"
    def __new__(cls, arg=0.0):
        return float.__new__(cls, float(arg)/12)

class inch_to_meter(float):
    "Convert from inch to meter"
    def __new__(cls, arg=0.0):
        return float.__new__(cls, arg*0.0254)

print inch_to_meter(5)  # 0.127
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a completely different answer that uses a metaclass and requires the conversion functions to be`staticmethods`rather than`classmethods`-- which it turns into properties based on the target unit's name. If searches for the names of any conversion functions itself, eliminating the need to manually define`from_to`type tables.

One thing about this approach is that the conversion functions aren't even called unless indirect references are made to the units associated with them. Another is that they're dynamic in the sense that the results returned will reflect the current value of the instance (unlike instances of three_pineapples'`length`class, which stores the results of calling them on the numeric value of the instance when it's initially constructed).

You've never said what version of Python you're using, so the following code is for Python 2.2 - 2.x.

```
import re

class MetaUnit(type):
    def __new__(metaclass, classname, bases, classdict):
        cls = type.__new__(metaclass, classname, bases, classdict)

        # add a constructor
        setattr(cls, '__init__',
                lambda self, value=0: setattr(self, '_value', value))

        # add a property for getting and setting the underlying value
        setattr(cls, 'value',
                property(lambda self: self._value,
                         lambda self, value: setattr(self, '_value', value)))

        # add an identity property the just returns the value unchanged
        unitname = classname.lower()  # lowercase classname becomes name of unit
        setattr(cls, unitname, property(lambda self: self._value))

        # find conversion methods and create properties that use them
        matcher = re.compile(unitname + r'''_to_(?P<target_unitname>\w+)''')
        for name in cls.__dict__.keys():
            match = matcher.match(name)
            if match:
                target_unitname = match.group('target_unitname').lower()
                fget = (lambda self, conversion_method=getattr(cls, name):
                            conversion_method(self._value))
                setattr(cls, target_unitname, property(fget))

        return cls
```

Sample usage:

```
scalar_conversion_staticmethod = (
    lambda scale_factor: staticmethod(lambda value: value * scale_factor))

class Inch(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaUnit
    inch_to_foot = scalar_conversion_staticmethod(1./12.)
    inch_to_meter = scalar_conversion_staticmethod(0.0254)

a = Inch(3)
print a.inch   # 3
print a.meter  # 0.0762
print a.foot   # 0.25
a.value = 6
print a.inch   # 6
print a.meter  # 0.1524
print a.foot   # 0.5
```

Comment: Whoa, pretty slick!  You're obviously more versatile with python than I am.  I don't know anything about metaclasses.  Not yet, anyway.  I need to get going on this project, so I am not going to have time to learn metaclasses right now, but this is something I will absolutely keep in mind for further revs.  Thanks so much for all the coding you did here!